# SecretKeySpec for ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to convert this code into java but the results are not accurate

```
private String hmacDigest(String msg, String keyString, String algo) throws Exception {
    String digest = null;
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), algo);
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algo);
    mac.init(key);

    byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes("ASCII"));

    StringBuffer hash = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            hash.append('0');
        }
        hash.append(hex);
    }
    digest = hash.toString();
    return digest;
}
```

and my codfusion try till this point

```
<cfset keybytes = BinaryDecode(SECRET_KEY, "Hex")>
<cfset databytes = CharsetDecode(data, "UTF-8")>
<cfset secret = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec").Init(keybytes,"HmacSHA256")>
<cfset mac = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Mac")>
<cfset mac = mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")>
<cfset mac.init(secret)>
<cfset digest = mac.doFinal(databytes)>
<cfset result = BinaryEncode(digest, "Base64")>
```

my knowledge is very limited in java so i am not sure if i am doing it right or wrong

Comment: 1) Do you mean you are trying to convert Java *into CFML*, correct?  2) Could you provide an example of the values used for `msg`, `keyString` and `algo` values AND the result?  Don't post real keys, just dummy keys used for dev testing.

Comment: basically i am using this SDK 
i had written code for CF but my signature is failing

Comment: https://github.com/PaymentRails/java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/ca/paymentrails/paymentrails/Client.java

Comment: for configration this is the java file

Comment: https://github.com/PaymentRails/java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/ca/paymentrails/paymentrails/Configuration.java

Comment: I'd need to see the actual values you used to be certain - but the problem is almost certainly due to a difference in encoding between java and CF. That said - the CF code for HMAC is actually a one-liner. If you use the same values in java - these results match the output of that function https://trycf.com/gist/b00dde3c00344fe5d96da34c98023aab/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: i used this to do in cf https://trycf.com/gist/0d1f8ca6cc68c67f8e08ec67b1f67bf5/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: Unfortunately hashing is extremely sensitive. Without the literal strings you used for testing (key="abc....", requestTimeStamp="123456...") it's impossible to reproduce the exact results you're getting. However [My example](https://trycf.com/gist/b00dde3c00344fe5d96da34c98023aab/lucee5?theme=monokai) produces the same results in java and CF.  If it's still not working for you - please create a runnable example - with a DUMMY secret key and data - that's safe to post here :)

Comment: ... Also `'\n'` is a line break in java. It doesn't work in CF. Instead use `chr(10)`.

Comment: i do not have a dummy key, but i can share the key if needed, its really needed. please guide, that might help

Comment: but do you think the timstamp i created is right or wrong

Comment: i did it like this  : <cfset var requestTimeStamp = int(gettickcount()/1000)>

Comment: `do you think the timstamp i created is right or wrong` I don't know the API so I have no idea. One step at a time. Get the same result from the hmacDigest() function, then on to the next problem.

Comment: ok, let me generate the data as per your method and will share the data result

Comment: Did you try [the CF example](https://trycf.com/gist/b00dde3c00344fe5d96da34c98023aab/lucee5?theme=monokai)? Those java method hmacDigest() produces the exact same result with those test values.

Comment: this is my gist https://trycf.com/gist/3058b8bdecd1be4ee5fad3891d632524/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: that is how the CF way with real values and real data, the api end point is: https://api.sandbox.paymentrails.com

Comment: https://trycf.com/gist/f48a60108fe867f26df5672880bc0c65/acf2021?theme=monokai

Comment: yes i tried you example and posted my results in the gist i shared above

Comment: It produces the exact same result as java hmacDigest() only CF upper cases everything. LCASE() the `requestSignature` value and it matches exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the string encodings, so the CFML is actually using different input values than the java code. That's why your results don't match

1. The java method decodes the key as "UTF-8"

   ```
   (keyString).getBytes("UTF-8")
   ```

   .. but the CFML is using "hexadecimal"

   ```
   <cfset keybytes = BinaryDecode(SECRET_KEY, "Hex")>
   ```
2. The java method decodes the message as "ASCII"

   ```
   msg.getBytes("ASCII")
   ```

   ... but the CFML is using "UTF-8"

   ```
   CharsetDecode(data, "UTF-8")
   ```
3. The java result is encoded as "hexadecimal", but the CFML is using "base64"

   ```
   BinaryEncode(digest, "Base64")
   ```
4. `\n` is interpreted as line feed in java. It doesn't work the same way in CF. Instead use `chr(10)`.

While the errors are easily fixed, the java code isn't even needed. Use the built in [HMAC](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) function instead. It produces the same result. The only difference being that CF returns hexadecimal in all upper case, so you must wrap it in [LCASE()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lcase.html) to get an exact match.

```
Lcase( HMac( messageString, keyAsString, algorithm, "ASCII") )
```